# Place Variable Into Array

Tags: perl, cgi

How can I place a variable into an array here is what i have tried with no luck.

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl

    use CGI qw(:standard);
    use CGI::Carp qw(warningsToBrowser fatalsToBrowser);
    use strict;

    my $State = "Alabama 205 251 256 334 659 938";

    my @Array = qw($State);

    print "@Array";
```

Comment: You should always `use warnings`.

Comment: You should clarify what result you are after, as there are many interpretations as to what "place a variable into an array" means.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`qw` is a special operator that quotes words, it does not interpolate. If you want the array to contain the words, you can use [split](http://p3rl.org/split):

```
my @Array = split / /, $State;
```

Comment: `split ' '` is (magically) closer to what qw does than `split / /`

Answer (score 2):

I take it you mean how can you put those space separated values in the string into array form?

```
my @Array = split ' ', $State;
```

That is assuming you can't put the values in directly, of course, like this:

```
my @Array = qw(Alabama 205 251 256 334 659 938);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to either [`push`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/push.html) it in or just simply put it in a list. [`qw`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/qw.html) takes your string "$State" literally and does not use the value of the variable.

```
my @arr = ($State);
my @arr2;
push @arr2, $State, $State;
```

Now you get:

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper \@arr, \@arr2;

$VAR1 = [ "Alabama 205 251 256 334 659 938" ];
$VAR2 = [ "Alabama 205 251 256 334 659 938", "Alabama 205 251 256 334 659 938" ];
```

---

Note that `push` pushes the value at the end of the array.

```
my @array;
for my $n (0 .. 5) {
  push @array, $n;  
}
print Dumper \@array;

$VAR1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

To get to them, use the scalar notation and start your index counting with 0:

```
use feature qw(say);
say $array[0];
say $array[5];

0
5
```